# Can't save Jasypt encrypted password to .properties file

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to store some strings in a .properties file. Now i want to encrypt those strings with Jasypt. But when I try to save this to the .properties file it is missing the surrounding "ENC()". When i try to insert this manually, the string is stored in clear text. Why?

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("123456789");
Properties prop = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
prop.setProperty("key", "ENC(" + encryptor.encrypt("value") + ")");
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.application-name/config.properties"), "Test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JDK source code explains what's happening here.  The cause is the class hierarchy involved; `org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties` extends `java.util.Properties` which in turn extends `java.util.Hashtable`.

So when `prop.store()` is called, the method from `java.util.Properties` is invoked:

```
public void store(OutputStream out, String comments)
    throws IOException
{
    store0(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "8859_1")),
           comments,
           true);
}

private void store0(BufferedWriter bw, String comments, boolean escUnicode)
    throws IOException
{
    if (comments != null) {
        writeComments(bw, comments);
    }
    bw.write("#" + new Date().toString());
    bw.newLine();
    synchronized (this) {
        for (Enumeration e = keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            String key = (String)e.nextElement();
            String val = (String)get(key);
            key = saveConvert(key, true, escUnicode);
            /* No need to escape embedded and trailing spaces for value, hence
             * pass false to flag.
             */
            val = saveConvert(val, false, escUnicode);
            bw.write(key + "=" + val);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw.flush();
}
```

The interesting line is

```
String val = (String)get(key);
```

`EncryptableProperties` defines a

```
public Object get(Object key)
```

method, overriding that of `java.util.Hashtable` - [see the Jasypt API docs for EncryptableProperties](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/properties/EncryptableProperties.html#get(java.lang.Object)). Hence the method below is invoked, which as you can see by reading the `decode` method, will perform the decryption, which in your case is not what you want!

```
public synchronized Object get(final Object key) {
    final Object value = super.get(key);
    final String valueStr = 
            (value instanceof String) ? (String)value : null;
    return decode(valueStr);
}


private synchronized String decode(final String encodedValue) {

    if (!PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.isEncryptedValue(encodedValue)) {
        return encodedValue;
    }
    if (this.stringEncryptor != null) {
        return PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(encodedValue, this.stringEncryptor);

    }
    if (this.textEncryptor != null) {
        return PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(encodedValue, this.textEncryptor);
    }

    /*
     * If neither a StringEncryptor nor a TextEncryptor can be retrieved
     * from the registry, this means that this EncryptableProperties
     * object has been serialized and then deserialized in a different
     * classloader and virtual machine, which is an unsupported behaviour. 
     */
    throw new EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException(
            "Neither a string encryptor nor a text encryptor exist " +
            "for this instance of EncryptableProperties. This is usually " +
            "caused by the instance having been serialized and then " +
            "de-serialized in a different classloader or virtual machine, " +
            "which is an unsupported behaviour (as encryptors cannot be " +
            "serialized themselves)");

}
```

To avoid this, don't use `EncryptableProperties` to store your properties, just using `java.util.Properties` will do. Simply replace

```
Properties prop = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
```

with

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
```

and the encrypted values will be stored in the properties file.